# Crash Report in C++ Mingw on windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, qt, mingw

I am trying to write crash report in c++ Qt on windows with MingW. I took reference from https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/01/13/exceptions-stack-traces-c/
but my code does not compile and giving following errors-
I am using this code on windows 10 with Qt 5.4.0 mingw. I am getting few errors while compiling this code.
**error: undefined reference to `_imp__SymInitialize@12′
error: undefined reference to`_imp__SymGetModuleBase@8′
error: undefined reference to `_imp__SymFunctionTableAccess@8′
error: undefined reference to`_imp__StackWalk@36′
error: undefined reference to `_imp__SymCleanup@4′**

These errors are from following code.

```
void windows_print_stacktrace(CONTEXT* context)
{
  SymInitialize(GetCurrentProcess(), 0, true);

  STACKFRAME frame = { 0 };

  /* setup initial stack frame */
  frame.AddrPC.Offset         = context->Eip;
  frame.AddrPC.Mode           = AddrModeFlat;
  frame.AddrStack.Offset      = context->Esp;
  frame.AddrStack.Mode        = AddrModeFlat;
  frame.AddrFrame.Offset      = context->Ebp;
  frame.AddrFrame.Mode        = AddrModeFlat;

  while (StackWalk(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386 ,
                   GetCurrentProcess(),
                   GetCurrentThread(),
                   &frame,
                   context,
                   0,
                   SymFunctionTableAccess,
                   SymGetModuleBase,
                   0 ) )
  {
    addr2line(icky_global_program_name, (void*)frame.AddrPC.Offset);
  }

  SymCleanup( GetCurrentProcess() );
}
```

imagehlp.dll is responsible for above functions.
Can someone tell me how to resolve this type of errors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Looks as if you didn't add the `imagehlp.lib` import library to your build? i.e. add it to the list of other platform libraries. If you had to add an include path for `<imagehlp.h>` then you'll probably find `imagehlp.lib` in a sibling directory.

Comment: I did it. but still same errors. Is there any way to check which version of dll it needed. because I am working on windows 10 64 bit machine and already system has many imagehlp.dll in many folders like system32.

Comment: ImageHlp has gone through many versions and does get redistributed a lot with other tools. However the specific DLL isn't (yet) your problem as it's failing to link the import library (.lib). It looks as if you're compiling for 32bit x86 but may have chosen the import library for the 64 bit DLL - I have as sibling directories "\x32\ImageHlp.Lib" and "\x64\ImageHlp.Lib".

Answer (score 0):

Mingw64 has the hability of linking directly to the dll, which is a bit slower but less error prone than msvc import libs - which seems to be incompatible with recent mingw64 more times than not. Make sure the dll is listed as a target (or as -L  -limagehlp if that works) *after* all objects/sources which depends on it.